# could not find driver for session in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

[image: Screenshot of the error dialog.]

I got the error like the picture and I don't know what is the cause of the error cause I did not open the project for a week and its becoming like that before it can be work just fine, as I also add livewire and jet stream but I did not use it in the coding

Comment: try clear cache with `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: already did but still got the same error

Comment: can i disable the session log so i dun use the session as a bypass?

Answer (score -1):

jet work for you but you updated db i suggest

> php artisan migrate

Comment: Already did the migrate:fresh but still the same error